# pgadmin 6.20 running in docker on ubuntu, problem with binaries path

Tags: docker, pgadmin-4

I've spent some hours googling and messing around with this but can't figure it out.

Running pgadmin 6.20 in docker on Ubuntu 22.04 VM. Postgres installed on same VM, but "bare metal" instead of docker.

pgadmin and postgres both seem to be working just fine.
Trouble I'm having is when I select a table in pgadmin, right-click and select "Import/Export data" it comes up with the following error:

> '/usr/local/pgsql-14/psql' file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog.'
> I have tried /usr/bin but I don't know that that applies here.

Here is my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin_bca
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: user@email.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: supersecretpassword
    volumes:
      - ./pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
      - ./pg-14:/usr/local/pgsql-14
      - ./pg-13:/usr/local/pgsql-13
      - ./pg-12:/usr/local/pgsql-12
      - ./pg-11:/usr/local/pgsql-11
      - ./pg-10:/usr/local/pgsql-10
volumes:
  pgadmin-data:
```

I had wondered if there was some issue running pgadmin in docker and postgres on bare metal, but that seems like it should be just fine.

Any thoughts on resolving this would be much appreciated :)
Thanks,
Mike